# wmic call in python return invalid query error

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, wmic

I'm trying to create a python executable that will run multiple wmic calls to check the versions of portable executables.

The following code works in the command prompt, so I attempted to run the same line from python

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" get Version /value
```

Python Code:

```
import subprocess

spath = r'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'
cargs = ["wmic","datafile","where", r'name="{0}"'.format(spath), "get", "Version", "/value"]

process = subprocess.check_output(cargs)
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-3271c59ed48f> in <module>()
----> 1 process = subprocess.check_output(cargs)

c:\users\jhsiang\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    624 
    625     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 626                **kwargs).stdout
    627 
    628 

c:\users\jhsiang\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    706         if check and retcode:
    707             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 708                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    709     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    710 

CalledProcessError: Command '['wmic', 'datafile', 'where', 'name="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"', 'get', 'Version', '/value']' returned non-zero exit status 2147749911
```

The command at the end of the error message looks correct to me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: a command line `wmic datafile where name="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" get Version /value` doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When executing the query from console (*Cmd*), the *BackSlash*es in the path are **doubled** (escaped):
`wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" get Version /value`

According to [[MS.Learn]: WHERE Clause (WMI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/where-clause) (**emphasis** is mine):

> You may use string literals, such as "NTFS", in a WHERE clause. If you wish to include the following special characters in your string, **you must first escape the character by prefixing the character with a backslash (\)**:
>
> - backslash (\)
> - double quotes (\")
> - single quotes (\')

Do the same thing in *Python*:

> ```py
> >>> import subprocess as sp
> >>>
> >>> spath = r"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe"
> >>> cargs = ("wmic", "datafile", "where", "name=\"{:s}\"".format(spath), "get", "Version", "/value")
> >>> process = sp.check_output(cargs)
> >>> process.strip().decode()
> 'Version=11.0.16299.15'
> ```

Comment: so it's not really a python question, but your code works, good answer. Microsoft are so hard to read sometimes. They invented backslash path separator to annoy unix users and now it backfires...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That's true, it's a *WMI* / *WQL* question, *Python* is just a wrapper, that doesn't have anything to do with the question per se.

Comment: but you provided the solution how to call from python, with raw string + double slashes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: you're right, it's my turn to get confused :)